# Extracting VideoId from Youtube urls

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have to get videoId from Youtube links and pass it to the mediaplayer.My code for Extracting videoId is

```C#
namespace Sample
{
    public partial class VideoPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        Movie movie;

        // Constructor
        public VideoPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var app = App.Current as App;
            movie = app.selectedMovie;
            string video = movie.MovieWatchLink;//MoviewatchLink contains youtube url and I was storing it in video//
            string a = video.ToString().Remove(0, 32);
            movie.MovieId = a.Substring(0, 11);
         }

         protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
         {
             var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(movie.MovieId, YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(url);
             player.Source = url.Uri;
         }     
     }
}
```

This is working very fine for urls of type  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLUbJtlBtHM]

And not working for urls type    http://youtu.be/RjqEgSW7F9w

http://www.youtube.com/movie?v=VPUMDrBjzC4

Please tell me how can I extract VideoId from the above two url types.My feed includes all the three types of urls and I am not knowing how to extract from them.

Comment: I think for the shortened urls you can expand it by using any available api like [Longurl.org](http://longurl.org). 

And i am not sure about third kind of urls though. I have tried to click that link and it seems redirected to the first type of url again. So i think you can just replace 'movie' to 'watch'.

Comment: Match it using regular expression then split the string.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with some sort of URL parser here rather than rely on character counts with `Substring`, etc. Unfortunately `System.Uri` gives you nothing for query string parsing and `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` is not available on Windows Phone 8.

You could try my [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) library, which is portable and will help you out in both scenarios:

```
using Flurl;

var url = new Url(movie.MovieWatchLink);
if (url.Path.StartsWith("http://www.youtube.com"))
    movie.MovieId = url.QueryParams["v"];
else if (url.Path.StartsWith("http://youtu.be"))
    movie.MovieId = url.Path.Split('/').Last();
```

Comment: Thankyou.I was coming across error.The type or namespace name 'url' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)Can you please tell me whta namespace or assembly is o be added.

Comment: It's in the Flurl namespace. Did you install Flurl from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl/)? If it's in your project just add `using Flurl;` as in my example.

Comment: I already had Nuget in my project.And updated also.but the process for insatlling Flurl from nuget is not going in the same process as mention in the link you provided.Can you please tell me hoe to install Flurl from Nuget.